# Unable to create bucket using domain name under google cloud storage - Server Error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm unable to create a domain name bucket under google cloud storage.

I get this error message:

**Server Error
Whoops! Our bad.
Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Copy the tracking number below, and include it with your feedback. Thanks!
Tracking Number: undefined**

Any thoughts? I tried putting any other domain name just in case it was specific to my domain and I keep getting the same message.

Comment: There was a small [issue today](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gs-announce/_INDTRQM2dk/discussion). Are you still seeing the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is related to the domain verification. It's a google bug. You should open the Chrome developer tool and see the JSON response which provides some useful information.